# Trying a variable as value in form inside link

Tags: php, database, forms

okay this is driving me nuts. I have tried all different ways and I can't get it to work.
I am trying to use a variable in a db form value which sounds easy. My db form has 2 fields 1 of which is

```
$mls   = isset($_POST['Mls'])      ? $_POST['Mls']      : ''; 
$plink = isset($_POST['Plink']) ? $_POST['Plink'] : ''; 

<input name="Mls" type="text" size="20" id="Mls">
```

which works fine

another form field I need the value of that form field to be in my link

```
<input type="text" name="Plink" id="Plink" value="<a href= http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx/listings'Mls'view.php>Mls</a>" />
```

It shows as Mls no matter how I put it. That Mls field will eventually be a folder that is created later on so I need it to put

```
<a href= http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/listings'MLS'view.php>MLS here</a>"
```

Comment: Ok so exactly what does that mean? My form starts out with               <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> as the action

Comment: Figured it out myself.